# Migration path from Web Applications to Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, stackexchange-2.0

I have seen several people on the [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) site asking questions that are related to *building* web applications rather than *using* web applications. I think it would be useful to be able to migrate those questions to Stack Overflow.

Examples:

1. <strike>https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8464/how-to-quickly-make-web-application-where-user-can-post-stuff</strike>
2. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8586/using-sound-on-website-for-smartphones-iphone-blackberry-android
3. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8768/how-to-emebed-a-progressbar-into-a-html-form
4. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/how-could-you-grab-an-avatar-from-gravatar-closed
5. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/problem-facebook-application-does-not-publish-on-the-wall-closed
6. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/in-which-language-should-i-develop-my-social-networking-application-closed
7. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/what-is-the-best-relational-database-management-system-dbms-to-use-with-a-web-a
8. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7218/vs2010-how-do-you-handle-long-paths-with-packaged-one-click-deployments-in
9. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/need-a-simple-php-framwork-for-my-webapp-closed
10. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8806/how-to-create-the-application-in-facebook-closed
11. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8751/get-the-number-of-tweets-likes-and-diggs-for-any-given-url
12. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8852/location-from-ip-address-closed

Comment: Would be useful to add links as evidence. If I come across any I will edit the question.

Comment: I think your first example is not a question for StackOverflow... because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Here's another one: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8751/get-the-number-of-tweets-likes-and-diggs-for-any-given-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok -- I added the migration path, may take 24 hours to pick it up.